# ошибка: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, c++11

в общем в opengl пытаюсь вывести текст, в opengl проекте. Но почему то выходит какая то синтаксическая ошибка.

Вот добавленный в проект код, почему жалуется на "превращения" хотя все заголовочные подключены

```
void RenderText(std::string message, SDL_Color color, int x, int y, int size) {
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluOrtho2D(0, gWindowWidth, 0, gWindowHeight); // m_Width and m_Height is the resolution of window
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    TTF_Font * font = TTF_OpenFont("pathToFont.ttf", size);
    SDL_Surface * sFont = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, message, color);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, sFont->w, sFont->h, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sFont->pixels);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
    glTexCoord2f(0,0); glVertex2f(x, y);
    glTexCoord2f(1,0); glVertex2f(x + sFont->w, y);
    glTexCoord2f(1,1); glVertex2f(x + sFont->w, y + sFont->h);
    glTexCoord2f(0,1); glVertex2f(x, y + sFont->h);
    }
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();

    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);
    TTF_CloseFont(font);
    SDL_FreeSurface(sFont);
}
```

вот ошибка

```
/home/comp/Qt_project/two/main.cpp:82: ошибка: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘SDL_Surface* TTF_RenderText_Blended(TTF_Font*, const char*, SDL_Color)’
     SDL_Surface * sFont = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, message, color);
                                                                  ^
```

Некак не могу понять откуда она `<string>` подключён, СТД аж всю дивизию подключил `<SDL2/SDL.h> <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h> <SDL2/SDL_video.h> <SDL2/SDL_render.h> <SDL2/SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h>`
Библиотеки также подключены.

Я догадываюсь что проблема в том что "компилятор может чего то не иметь " но незнаю как обойти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TTF_RenderText_Blended` принимает С-строку (`const char *`), а вы ему передаете `std::string`.

`message` -> `message.c_str()`